# Check values of column 1 present in values of column 2

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains a large number of rows, and a column of interest.
From data frame 2, I have a list oof entries, which may/ may not be present in the column of interest from data frame 1.

While making the considerations, I realised the entry in the column of interest from data frame 1 may be unfriendly format.

Sample from column of interest of data frame 1:

```
> dput(GSE20069_GPL6246.character[1:50,1])
c("", "---", "ab010088 // kl // klotho // 5|5 g3 // 16591 /// nm_013823 // kl // klotho // 5|5 g3 // 16591 /// ensmust00000078856 // kl // klotho // 5|5 g3 // 16591 /// ab005141 // kl // klotho // 5|5 g3 // 16591 /// bc138258 // kl // klotho // 5|5 g3 // 16591 /// bc138259 // kl // klotho // 5|5 g3 // 16591", 
"ab017785 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117 /// ab018421 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117 /// bc010747 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117 /// bc051049 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117 /// nm_010011 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117 /// ensmust00000058785 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117 /// ensmust00000094886 // cyp4a10 // cytochrome p450, family 4, subfamily a, polypeptide 10 // 4 d1|4 53.05 cm // 13117", 
"ab026804 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// ab075900 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// ab075901 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// bc139806 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// nm_173068 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// ensmust00000169121 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// nm_018801 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// nm_173067 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// ensmust00000073899 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525 /// ensmust00000076968 // syt7 // synaptotagmin vii // 19|19 b // 54525", 
"ab041855 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816 /// bc128480 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816 /// nm_029546 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816 /// xm_006513066 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816 /// ensmust00000042556 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816 /// bc112325 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816 /// bc117903 // pwp2 // pwp2 periodic tryptophan protein homolog (yeast) // 10 c1|10 39.72 cm // 110816", 
"ab042399 // fezf2 // fez family zinc finger 2 // 14 a1|14 // 54713 /// bc055718 // fezf2 // fez family zinc finger 2 // 14 a1|14 // 54713 /// nm_080433 // fezf2 // fez family zinc finger 2 // 14 a1|14 // 54713 /// ensmust00000022262 // fezf2 // fez family zinc finger 2 // 14 a1|14 // 54713", 
"ab045721 // spata20 // spermatogenesis associated 20 // 11 d|11 // 217116", 
"ab052758 // tra2a // transformer 2 alpha homolog (drosophila) // 6 b2.3|6 // 101214 /// ak005187 // tra2a // transformer 2 alpha homolog (drosophila) // 6 b2.3|6 // 101214 /// ak148552 // tra2a // transformer 2 alpha homolog (drosophila) // 6 b2.3|6 // 101214", 
"ab055635 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// ab055636 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// ak129042 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// ay389498 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// bc003979 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// nm_001081457 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// nm_001081458 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// nm_012023 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// ensmust00000084985 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// ensmust00000109832 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931 /// nm_001135001 // ppp2r5c // protein phosphatase 2, regulatory subunit b, gamma // 12 f1|12 60.56 cm // 26931", 
"ab062122 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// ak146170 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// nm_008859 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// xm_006497398 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// ensmust00000028118 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// ensmust00000102970 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// ak037664 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// bc138552 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// bc145769 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// d11091 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// ensmust00000114853 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761 /// ak085546 // prkcq // protein kinase c, theta // 2 a1|2 8.42 cm // 18761", 
"ab095735 // dtl // denticleless homolog (drosophila) // 1 h6|1 // 76843 /// ab095736 // dtl // denticleless homolog (drosophila) // 1 h6|1 // 76843 /// nm_029766 // dtl // denticleless homolog (drosophila) // 1 h6|1 // 76843 /// ensmust00000027933 // dtl // denticleless homolog (drosophila) // 1 h6|1 // 76843 /// ak164999 // dtl // denticleless homolog (drosophila) // 1 h6|1 // 76843 /// ak012919 // dtl // denticleless homolog (drosophila) // 1 h6|1 // 76843", 
"ab154249 // fam174a // family with sequence similarity 174, member a // 1 d|1 // 67698 /// nm_026321 // fam174a // family with sequence similarity 174, member a // 1 d|1 // 67698 /// ensmust00000059975 // fam174a // family with sequence similarity 174, member a // 1 d|1 // 67698 /// bc021428 // fam174a // family with sequence similarity 174, member a // 1 d|1 // 67698", 
"ab244988 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// bc058796 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// nm_025840 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// xm_006515164 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// xm_006515166 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// ensmust00000020856 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// ak162647 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912 /// bc013060 // bzw2 // basic leucine zipper and w2 domains 2 // 12|12 b2 // 66912", 
"ab473727 // fam71b // family with sequence similarity 71, member b // 11 b1.1|11 // 432552 /// bc150988 // fam71b // family with sequence similarity 71, member b // 11 b1.1|11 // 432552 /// nm_001013783 // fam71b // family with sequence similarity 71, member b // 11 b1.1|11 // 432552 /// ensmust00000063166 // fam71b // family with sequence similarity 71, member b // 11 b1.1|11 // 432552", 
"af031663 // strm // striamin // 12 c3|12 // 100504617", "af037046 // gm8479 // thiopurine s-methyltransferase pseudogene // 6 c1|6 // 667141 /// af037047 // gm8479 // thiopurine s-methyltransferase pseudogene // 6 c1|6 // 667141", 
"af044257 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// bc050049 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// bc055378 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// bc138606 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// bc138608 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// nm_011770 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// xm_006495962 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// ensmust00000027146 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779 /// xm_006495959 // ikzf2 // ikaros family zinc finger 2 // 1 c3|1 // 22779", 
"af071025 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// af087568 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// af326557 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// af326558 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// ak152474 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// bc099945 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// nm_008917 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// xr_376299 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// ensmust00000030412 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// ensmust00000120157 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// ensmust00000097902 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// ensmust00000121870 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063 /// ak148314 // ppt1 // palmitoyl-protein thioesterase 1 // 4 d1-d3|4 57.27 cm // 19063", 
"af075717 // tiaf2 // tgf-beta1-induced anti-apoptotic factor 2 // 15 b1|15 // 223431", 
"af080252 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// bc016676 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// bc051072 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// nm_001029843 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// nm_001029844 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// nm_011705 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// xm_006515810 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// ensmust00000021539 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// ensmust00000072040 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// ensmust00000085026 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// af080253 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367 /// ak088674 // vrk1 // vaccinia related kinase 1 // 12|12 f1 // 22367", 
"af082803 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// af234831 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// l19057 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ab196800 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ab196801 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ab196802 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ab196803 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// dq167570 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// dq167571 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// af184208 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ak171232 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// bc145067 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// bc150692 // loc677008 // natural killer cell receptor 2b4-like // 1|1 // 677008 /// nm_018729 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// xm_006496695 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ensmust00000004829 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// xr_373597 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// af234830 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106 /// ak171544 // cd244 // cd244 natural killer cell receptor 2b4 // 1 h3|1 79.52 cm // 18106", 
"af096867 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965 /// nm_001111015 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965 /// nm_013681 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965 /// ensmust00000009538 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965 /// ensmust00000169345 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965 /// bc085129 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965 /// ak043584 // syn2 // synapsin ii // 6 f|6 53.2 cm // 20965", 
"af138740 // iglv1 // immunoglobulin lambda variable 1 // 16 a3|16 11.82 cm // 16142 /// bc106994 // iglv1 // immunoglobulin lambda variable 1 // 16 a3|16 11.82 cm // 16142 /// hq724329 // iglv1 // immunoglobulin lambda variable 1 // 16 a3|16 11.82 cm // 16142 /// m94350 // iglv1 // immunoglobulin lambda variable 1 // 16 a3|16 11.82 cm // 16142", 
"af165171 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// kc810035 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// nm_031180 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// ensmust00000031096 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// af165170 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// af178429 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// bc138008 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379 /// bc138010 // klb // klotho beta // 5 c3.1|5 // 83379", 
"af182064 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// af182065 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// af182066 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// bc116911 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// bc144863 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// nm_015768 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// ensmust00000032152 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// nm_001037539 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// nm_001170419 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// ensmust00000008273 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// ensmust00000101120 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501 /// af487280 // prok2 // prokineticin 2 // 6 d3|6 46.29 cm // 50501", 
"af184240 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// bc030378 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// bc066815 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// nm_001166456 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// nm_001166458 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// nm_134086 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// xm_006520235 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// ensmust00000088452 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// ensmust00000088454 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// ensmust00000100262 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727 /// ak029189 // slc38a1 // solute carrier family 38, member 1 // 15 f1|15 // 105727", 
"af197480 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464 /// bc115438 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464 /// nm_019861 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464 /// ensmust00000119694 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464 /// af136280 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464 /// bc058758 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464 /// ak165416 // ctsf // cathepsin f // 19 a|19 // 56464", 
"af222802 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// bc057895 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// nm_022015 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// ensmust00000067103 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// xm_006524764 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// xm_006524767 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// ak049949 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856 /// ak162110 // taf8 // taf8 rna polymerase ii, tata box binding protein (tbp)-associated factorq // 17 c|17 // 63856", 
"af223569 // gm5037 // frataxin pseudogene // 7 e1|7 // 260347", 
"af285583 // tex18 // testis expressed gene 18 // 10 c1|10 // 83559", 
"af287293 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614 /// af401483 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614 /// ak046496 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614 /// bc021361 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614 /// nm_134093 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614 /// ensmust00000037001 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614 /// ak041312 // letmd1 // letm1 domain containing 1 // 15 f1|15 // 68614", 
"af297082 // gucy1a3 // guanylate cyclase 1, soluble, alpha 3 // 3 e3|3 // 60596 /// bc094310 // gucy1a3 // guanylate cyclase 1, soluble, alpha 3 // 3 e3|3 // 60596 /// nm_021896 // gucy1a3 // guanylate cyclase 1, soluble, alpha 3 // 3 e3|3 // 60596 /// ensmust00000048976 // gucy1a3 // guanylate cyclase 1, soluble, alpha 3 // 3 e3|3 // 60596 /// bc057327 // gucy1a3 // guanylate cyclase 1, soluble, alpha 3 // 3 e3|3 // 60596 /// ak031305 // gucy1a3 // guanylate cyclase 1, soluble, alpha 3 // 3 e3|3 // 60596", 
"af334612 // pdzd3 // pdz domain containing 3 // 9 a5.2|9 // 170761 /// nm_133226 // pdzd3 // pdz domain containing 3 // 9 a5.2|9 // 170761 /// ensmust00000034618 // pdzd3 // pdz domain containing 3 // 9 a5.2|9 // 170761", 
"af365933 // zfp264 // zinc finger protein 264 // 7 a1|7 // 101055709", 
"af391192 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// bc085184 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// nm_001177773 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// ensmust00000107679 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// ensmust00000151410 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// nm_001177774 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// nm_080428 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// xm_006501658 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// ensmust00000029727 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// ensmust00000107675 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// ensmust00000107678 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// af427101 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754 /// bc131648 // fbxw7 // f-box and wd-40 domain protein 7 // 3 e3.3|3 37.7 cm // 50754", 
"af408408 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// ak076119 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// bc040407 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// nm_130796 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// ensmust00000109241 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// bc063089 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// bc137801 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// bc145951 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625 /// ak143645 // snx18 // sorting nexin 18 // 13 d2.2|13 // 170625", 
"af422243 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898 /// af487898 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898 /// ak087083 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898 /// bc058555 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898 /// nm_153564 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898 /// ensmust00000090127 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898 /// ak035481 // gbp5 // guanylate binding protein 5 // 3 h1|3 // 229898", 
"af469169 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ak044074 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay484964 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay484965 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay728043 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay728044 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay803942 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay803943 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay803944 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// bc024526 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ct010362 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// u33012 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// u48397 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// u48398 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// u48399 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// u88623 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// nm_009700 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ensmust00000079081 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// af469168 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay484966 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829 /// ay728045 // aqp4 // aquaporin 4 // 18 a1|18 8.74 cm // 11829", 
"af548110 // ofcc1 // orofacial cleft 1 candidate 1 // 13 a5|13 // 218165 /// af548111 // ofcc1 // orofacial cleft 1 candidate 1 // 13 a5|13 // 218165 /// nm_172143 // ofcc1 // orofacial cleft 1 candidate 1 // 13 a5|13 // 218165 /// ensmust00000054635 // ofcc1 // orofacial cleft 1 candidate 1 // 13 a5|13 // 218165 /// eu683438 // ofcc1 // orofacial cleft 1 candidate 1 // 13 a5|13 // 218165 /// eu683439 // ofcc1 // orofacial cleft 1 candidate 1 // 13 a5|13 // 218165", 
"aj319753 // gm1549 // predicted gene 1549 // x a1.1|x // 260300", 
"ak002767 // plet1 // placenta expressed transcript 1 // 9|9 b // 76509 /// bc017624 // plet1 // placenta expressed transcript 1 // 9|9 b // 76509 /// bc022950 // plet1 // placenta expressed transcript 1 // 9|9 b // 76509 /// nm_029639 // plet1 // placenta expressed transcript 1 // 9|9 b // 76509 /// ensmust00000114474 // plet1 // placenta expressed transcript 1 // 9|9 b // 76509 /// ay364436 // plet1 // placenta expressed transcript 1 // 9|9 b // 76509", 
"ak003851 // 1110020c17rik // riken cdna 1110020c17 gene // 14 d1|14 // 68584", 
"ak005187 // tra2a // transformer 2 alpha homolog (drosophila) // 6 b2.3|6 // 101214 /// ak148552 // tra2a // transformer 2 alpha homolog (drosophila) // 6 b2.3|6 // 101214", 
"ak005461 // tbc1d5 // tbc1 domain family, member 5 // 17 c|17 // 72238 /// ensmust00000122634 // gm25177 // predicted gene, 25177 // --- // ---", 
"ak005585 // 1110058l19rik // riken cdna 1110058l19 gene // 1 a5|1 // 68002", 
"ak005805 // ai428898 // expressed sequence ai428898 // 4|4 // 100115", 
"ak005979 // fem1a // feminization 1 homolog a (c. elegans) // 17 d|17 29.24 cm // 14154", 
"ak006077 // 1700018a14rik // riken cdna 1700018a14 gene // 18 c|18 // 69391", 
"ak006338 // 1700025h01rik // riken cdna 1700025h01 gene // 16 b2|16 // 75531"
)
```

Here multiple values are separated by `//` and I want to maintain the integrity of the dataframe, i.e. dataframe has other columns too associated for each row of the column of interest and the entries need to be maintained.

The entries whose presence has to be checked in the column of interest is:

```
dput(gene.character)
c("cgnl1", "dysf", "pogk", "actg2", "sema3e", "neto2", "postn", 
"grem2", "ltbp4", "mmp13", "thsd7a", "nrcam", "zfp862-ps", "ptgs1", 
"tnfrsf11b", "tgfb2", "gm13415", "naalad2", "a730017l22rik", 
"runx3", "mga", "msra", "pkp1", "s1pr3", "daam2", "atoh8", "tenm4", 
"vdr", "rftn1", "gm14137", "stmn2", "il17ra", "kirrel3", "fmod", 
"kcnab2", "shroom2", "pcdh7", "dynap", "itga11", "riox1", "cacnb2", 
"kcnab1", "col5a3", "slc8a1", "gng2", "gramd1b", "mmp10", "ldb3", 
"itga2", "dkk2", "sh3bgrl2", "wincr1", "gda", "shroom3", "fmn2", 
"c1qtnf6", "neurl1b", "crispld2", "nipsnap1", "pcdh9", "rec114", 
"dlgap1", "fzd3", "zfp518b", "sh3rf2", "kcnq5", "sdcbp2", "phex", 
"ap1g2", "tcim", "slc2a13", "pcdhb18", "col27a1", "saysd1", "calcrl", 
"hsd17b11", "spns2", "jph2", "itm2a", "erg", "mmp24", "arhgap20", 
"prex2", "map3k5", "zfp273", "c3ar1", "epha7", "rgs17", "megf6", 
"ehd3", "fgl2", "lvrn", "pappa", "myh11", "dhrs3", "cav3", "hspb1", 
"xk", "islr", "spns3", "trim68", "arhgef3", "padi3", "gap43", 
"hpse2", "tmem144", "slc22a23", "gm10419", "cd53", "nckap5", 
"lin28b", "hs3st3b1", "isl1", "syt4", "guca1b", "msr1", "nr1h3", 
"clec1a", "prr16", "gm49490", "btn1a1", "gm4610", "slamf8", "dnaaf9", 
"Percentage TRUE")
```

It may seem that the middle term in the column of interest may contain the words which can match, but that is not true as the data frame has 25k entries, so this will not be the case everywhere, and all the words separated by `//` have to be considered.

Currently I'm using the following code:

```
gene.character$GSE20069_GPL6246 <- gene.character$list %in% GSE20069_GPL6246.character[,1]
```

If someone can please come up some method while maintaining the other columns, that will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try duplicating rows and let each column have a unique value which is between the `//`

Comment: @hmmmm I am unable to determine the number of duplications, as it may vary and I do not want to hard code it. This is precisely where I want some help.

Comment: You are more likely to receive an answer if (1) you reduce your toy data, (2) add expected output, and (3) make sure that your vectors (`GSE20069_GPL6246.character$column1` and `gene.character`) have at least one (partial) match. I cannot find any (based on brief visual inspection). Do we need to remove `|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach with base R:

```
catchwords <- c('foo', 'bar', 'tex18')

d <- data.frame(tags = c("af285583 // tex18 // testis expressed gene 18 // 10 c1|10 // 83559",
                         "tic // tac // toe"
                         )
                )
```

```
## > d
                                                                tags
## 1 af285583 // tex18 // testis expressed gene 18 // 10 c1|10 // 83559
## 2                                                  tic // tac // toe
```

use `strsplit` with a regular expression which splits at two or more slashes (your data appears to also contain triple slashes), also removing adjacent blanks; test whether these fragments intersect (= have common terms) with the list of catchwords:

```
d$has_catchword <-
  d$tags |>
  ## splits at two or more slashes with possibly adjacent blanks:
  strsplit(d$tags, split = ' ?/ ?{2,}') |> 
  Map(f = \(fragments) intersect(fragments, catchwords) |> length() |> as.logical()) |>
  unlist()
```

```
## > d
##                                                                 tags has_catchword
## 1 af285583 // tex18 // testis expressed gene 18 // 10 c1|10 // 83559          TRUE
## 2                                                  tic // tac // toe         FALSE
```

Comment: `d$tags` =  `GSE20069_GPL6246.character[, 1]`, `catchwords` = `gene.character`. What is `A$tags`?

Comment: sorry! `d$tags`, the column containing the slash-separated text; edited

Comment: Difficult to check. W.r.t. the Q, I suspect the output would be `rep(FALSE, 50L)` as the sample data is badly chosen.

Comment: Also, this approach collapses to `lapply(d$tags, \(x) grepl(paste(catchwords, collapse = "|"), x))` I think.

Answer (score 2):

You did not respond but accepted an answer. Hence, a possible solution as one-liner:

```r
lapply(GSE20069_GPL6246.character[, 1], \(x) grepl(paste(gene.character, collapse = "|"), x))
```

which results in `FALSE` repeated 50 times due to the unfortunate choice of sample data.