# Get ENSEMBL ID for Gene Symbols

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I'm downloading GSE files from Gene Expression Omnibus Site by NCBI. It so happens that I download expression by profiling data, and the files are GSExxxxx. There are expression tables in these lists when I load the data to RStudio. I extract the table, which has patient samples on one axis and gene id as denoted in the GPL files which helps map to gene information present in GPL files.
Therefore I download GPL files and based on the details there, there are gene symbols, gene names and other details but no ENSEMBL ID. This is of concern, as I wish to work with ENSEMBL ID for further manipulation, and I am not sure of methods on how to convert the IDs present in GSE files to ENSEMBL ID.

The code that I used to download thee files and map them are:

```
#####################
#Load Libraries
#####################
library(GEOquery)
library(Biobase)

GSE68266 <- getGEO('GSE68266')
GSE68266_assayData <- data.frame(GSE68266[["GSE68266_series_matrix.txt.gz"]]@assayData[["exprs"]])

GPL6246 <- getGEO('GPL6246')
GPL6246_table <- data.frame(GPL6246@dataTable@table)

GSE68266_assayData$ID<-row.names(GSE68266_assayData)
GSE68266_assayData_mapped <- merge(GPL6246_table,GSE68266_assayData,id="ID",all.y=TRUE)
GSE68266_assayData_mapped <- GSE68266_assayData_mapped[,c(10,13:24)]

GSE68266_assayData_mapped <- aggregate(. ~ gene_assignment, GSE68266_assayData_mapped, mean)
```

This code will download the GSE, GPL files, extract expression table and table which has information for GPL file, i.e., gene data. Later it will map thee ID from GSE file to GPL file and on looking at the mapped file with just gene symbol, I observe same gene has multiple rows, and I believe this issue is cause I am not using ENSEMBL ID, and therefore average it out.

This aside, I can now map gene symbol to ENSEMBL ID, but if there is a way which can do it before thee last step that will be helpful.

Since I have to upload sample file using dput, here is a preview:

```
> dput(GSE68266_assayData[1:10,])
structure(list(GSM1666885 = c(2.279918436, 2.988098845, 5.328025279, 
8.823735602, 4.026079799, 9.202864658, 11.94099064, 2.463023042, 
6.589012573, 7.454990691), GSM1666886 = c(2.417476409, 2.268637132, 
6.875015606, 9.230564408, 2.481822425, 8.370423349, 11.64948446, 
2.312504209, 6.684511479, 8.213245168), GSM1666887 = c(2.585641476, 
2.677200831, 5.757663918, 9.372965375, 2.825481565, 8.658368489, 
11.98599131, 3.272974828, 6.937436458, 8.353237578), GSM1666888 = c(2.162864114, 
3.13726422, 7.317097246, 9.326182314, 2.904886778, 7.725407155, 
11.9129236, 1.92055278, 6.99118628, 8.743269756), GSM1666889 = c(1.988852673, 
3.568596235, 7.481167388, 8.734948421, 2.952178107, 7.905551803, 
11.73671598, 2.164841887, 7.48221719, 8.100881444), GSM1666890 = c(1.875333405, 
2.956819009, 7.087370437, 8.825282857, 3.021162525, 8.361661077, 
11.66291834, 2.055539551, 6.72837364, 8.261053581), GSM1666891 = c(1.937082999, 
2.352105771, 7.478323665, 9.027936627, 2.518425346, 8.518543602, 
11.57667342, 2.208023413, 6.286188731, 8.334887789), GSM1666892 = c(1.888119534, 
3.075999923, 6.865026445, 9.003240261, 2.623163948, 8.360743911, 
11.65712158, 2.188155201, 6.816237296, 8.436395945), GSM1666893 = c(2.030701542, 
2.650094477, 6.860070811, 7.875834276, 3.139210335, 8.141316361, 
11.79825442, 2.708398602, 6.741807539, 7.921992279), GSM1666894 = c(2.270031274, 
2.614141652, 7.423814433, 8.586151005, 2.53645575, 7.486899179, 
11.8778601, 2.313362195, 6.860830315, 7.942532956), GSM1666895 = c(2.140678027, 
2.328710759, 7.141117451, 8.57790011, 2.855282591, 8.380166234, 
11.56798581, 2.61524144, 7.147135406, 7.965226555), GSM1666896 = c(2.163867142, 
2.593331698, 7.337511599, 9.004223666, 2.686137448, 8.145299847, 
11.77674285, 2.32668163, 7.583926092, 7.990832914), ID = c("10338071", 
"10338072", "10338075", "10338077", "10338084", "10338085", "10338095", 
"10338099", "10338104", "10338106")), row.names = c("10338071", 
"10338072", "10338075", "10338077", "10338084", "10338085", "10338095", 
"10338099", "10338104", "10338106"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(GPL6246_table[1:10,])
structure(list(ID = c(10344614L, 10344616L, 10344618L, 10344620L, 
10344622L, 10344624L, 10344633L, 10344637L, 10344653L, 10344658L
), GB_LIST = c("AK145513,AK145782", "", "", "AK140060", "", "NM_008866,XM_006495471,AK050549,AK167231,BC013536,BC052848,CT010201,U89352,AK016021,AK034851", 
"NM_001159750,NM_011541,BC061490,BC083127,M18210,BC006022", "NM_133826,XM_006495437,XM_006495438,BC009154,AK034165,AK081492", 
"NM_001204371,NM_011011,BC116795,BC119026,L11065,AK138198", "NM_009826,AB050017,AB070619,BC150774,XM_006495444"
), SPOT_ID = c("chr1:3054233-3054733", "chr1:3102016-3102125", 
"chr1:3276323-3277348", "chr1:3680571-3680912", "chr1:4771131-4772199", 
"chr1:4807862-4846736", "chr1:4857814-4897909", "chr1:5083172-5162549", 
"chr1:5588493-5602866", "chr1:6214662-6275575"), seqname = c("chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1"), RANGE_GB = c("NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6", 
"NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6", 
"NC_000067.6", "NC_000067.6"), RANGE_STRAND = c("+", "+", "+", 
"+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"), RANGE_START = c("3054233", 
"3102016", "3276323", "3680571", "4771131", "4807862", "4857814", 
"5083172", "5588493", "6214662"), RANGE_STOP = c("3054733", "3102125", 
"3277348", "3680912", "4772199", "4846736", "4897909", "5162549", 
"5602866", "6275575"), total_probes = c(33L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 8L, 
23L, 8L, 30L, 25L, 29L), gene_assignment = c("ENSMUST00000160944 // Gm16088 // predicted gene 16088 // --- // --- /// ENSMUST00000120800 // Gm14300 // predicted gene 14300 // --- // --- /// ENSMUST00000179907 // G430049J08Rik // RIKEN cDNA G430049J08 gene // --- // --- /// AK145513 // Gm2889 // predicted gene 2889 // 18 A1|18 // 100040658", 
"ENSMUST00000082908 // Gm26206 // predicted gene, 26206 // --- // ---", 
"---", "AK140060 // Gm10568 // predicted gene 10568 // --- // 100038431", 
"---", "NM_008866 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// XM_006495471 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000027036 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000115529 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000131119 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000137887 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000150971 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000155020 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// AK050549 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// AK167231 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// BC013536 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// BC052848 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// CT010201 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// U89352 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000134384 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000119612 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// ENSMUST00000141278 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// AK016021 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777 /// AK034851 // Lypla1 // lysophospholipase 1 // 1 A1|1 // 18777", 
"NM_001159750 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399 /// NM_011541 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399 /// ENSMUST00000081551 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399 /// BC061490 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399 /// BC083127 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399 /// M18210 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399 /// BC006022 // Tcea1 // transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 // 1 A1|1 // 21399", 
"NM_133826 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664 /// XM_006495437 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664 /// XM_006495438 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664 /// ENSMUST00000044369 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664 /// BC009154 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664 /// AK034165 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664 /// AK081492 // Atp6v1h // ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H // 1 A1|1 // 108664", 
"NM_001204371 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// NM_011011 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// ENSMUST00000027038 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// ENSMUST00000160339 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// ENSMUST00000160777 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// BC116795 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// BC119026 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// L11065 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// ENSMUST00000159083 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387 /// AK138198 // Oprk1 // opioid receptor, kappa 1 // 1 A2-A3|1 1.89 cM // 18387", 
"NM_009826 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// ENSMUST00000027040 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// ENSMUST00000159530 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// ENSMUST00000159656 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// ENSMUST00000161327 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// ENSMUST00000162257 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// AB050017 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// AB070619 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// BC150774 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// XM_006495444 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421 /// ENSMUST00000162795 // Rb1cc1 // RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 // 1|1 A2 // 12421"
), mrna_assignment = c("ENSMUST00000160944 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:3054233:3054733:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000090025 gene_biotype:pseudogene transcript_biotype:unprocessed_pseudogene // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 33 // 33 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000120800 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:2:179612622:179613567:-1 gene:ENSMUSG00000083410 gene_biotype:pseudogene transcript_biotype:processed_pseudogene // chr1 // 30 // 100 // 10 // 33 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000179907 // ENSEMBL // ensembl:known chromosome:GRCm38:18:3471630:3474315:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000096528 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// AK145513 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus blastocyst blastocyst cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:I1C0009C06 product:hypothetical DeoxyUTP pyrophosphatase/Aspartyl protease, retroviral-type family profile/Retrovirus capsid, C-terminal/Peptidase aspartic/Peptidase aspartic, active site containing protein, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 24 // 100 // 8 // 33 // 0 /// AK145782 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus blastocyst blastocyst cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:I1C0042P10 product:hypothetical protein, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 52 // 100 // 17 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00005135 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 52 // 100 // 17 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT044096 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 52 // 100 // 17 // 33 // 0 /// AK139746 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus 2 cells egg cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:B020014N01 product:hypothetical protein, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// AK145590 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus blastocyst blastocyst cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:I1C0019N16 product:unclassifiable, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// AK145750 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus blastocyst blastocyst cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:I1C0037K09 product:unclassifiable, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 36 // 85 // 10 // 28 // 0 /// AK165162 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus 8 cells embryo 8 cells cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:E860009L19 product:unclassifiable, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 48 // 100 // 16 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00001379 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00001380 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00002541 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 36 // 85 // 10 // 28 // 0 /// KnowTID_00003768 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00005134 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 45 // 100 // 15 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT013638 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT013641 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 42 // 100 // 14 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT021887 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 36 // 85 // 10 // 28 // 0 /// NONMMUT044095 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 45 // 100 // 15 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT046086 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 48 // 100 // 16 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT046087 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 48 // 100 // 16 // 33 // 0 /// AK145700 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus blastocyst blastocyst cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:I1C0031F10 product:hypothetical protein, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 24 // 100 // 8 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00003789 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 24 // 100 // 8 // 33 // 0 /// NONMMUT031618 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 24 // 100 // 8 // 33 // 0 /// KnowTID_00002704 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 24 // 24 // 8 // 33 // 1 /// NONMMUT023055 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 24 // 24 // 8 // 33 // 1", 
"ENSMUST00000082908 // ENSEMBL // ncrna:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:3102016:3102125:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000064842 gene_biotype:snRNA transcript_biotype:snRNA // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// NONMMUT000002 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0", 
"---", "AK140060 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus adult male corpora quadrigemina cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:B230115G11 product:hypothetical protein, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// KnowTID_00000002 // Luo lincRNA // Non-coding transcript identified by Luo, et al. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// NONMMUT000015 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Linc // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0", 
"GENSCAN00000005057 // ENSEMBL // cdna:genscan chromosome:GRCm38:1:4771131:4772199:1 transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 8 // 8 // 0", 
"NM_008866 // RefSeq // Mus musculus lysophospholipase 1 (Lypla1), mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 23 // 23 // 0 /// XM_006495471 // RefSeq // PREDICTED: Mus musculus lysophospholipase 1 (Lypla1), transcript variant X1, mRNA. // chr1 // 95 // 87 // 19 // 20 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000027036 // ENSEMBL // ensembl_havana_transcript:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807823:4846739:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 23 // 23 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000115529 // ENSEMBL // havana:novel chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807911:4845352:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 94 // 74 // 16 // 17 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000131119 // ENSEMBL // havana:putative chromosome:GRCm38:1:4808237:4841093:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 74 // 17 // 17 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000137887 // ENSEMBL // havana:novel chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807898:4840969:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 95 // 83 // 18 // 19 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000150971 // ENSEMBL // havana:putative chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807918:4841286:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 87 // 20 // 20 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000155020 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807892:4886770:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:nonsense_mediated_decay // chr1 // 100 // 74 // 17 // 17 // 0 /// AK050549 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus adult pancreas islet cells cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:C820014D19 product:lysophospholipase 1, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 100 // 87 // 20 // 20 // 0 /// AK167231 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus blastocyst blastocyst cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:I1C0043L13 product:lysophospholipase 1, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 91 // 100 // 21 // 23 // 0 /// BC013536 // GenBank // Mus musculus lysophospholipase 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:19218 IMAGE:4240573), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 23 // 23 // 0 /// BC052848 // GenBank // Mus musculus lysophospholipase 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:60679 IMAGE:30055025), complete cds. // chr1 // 96 // 100 // 22 // 23 // 0 /// CT010201 // GenBank // Mus musculus full open reading frame cDNA clone RZPDo836F0950D for gene Lypla1, Lysophospholipase 1; complete cds, incl. stopcodon. // chr1 // 100 // 87 // 20 // 20 // 0 /// U89352 // GenBank // Mus musculus lysophospholipase I mRNA, complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 87 // 20 // 20 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000134384 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807788:4848410:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:nonsense_mediated_decay // chr1 // 87 // 87 // 20 // 23 // 1 /// ENSMUST00000119612 // ENSEMBL // havana:putative chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807896:4845174:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 52 // 52 // 12 // 23 // 1 /// ENSMUST00000141278 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:4836905:4842827:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025903 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:retained_intron // chr1 // 35 // 35 // 8 // 23 // 1 /// AK016021 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus adult male testis cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:4930542E11 product:CALCIUM-INDEPENDENT PHOSPHOLIPASE A2 ISOFORM 2 homolog [Oryctolagus cuniculus], full insert sequence. // chr1 // 35 // 35 // 8 // 23 // 1 /// AK034851 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus 12 days embryo embryonic body between diaphragm region and neck cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:9430047N20 product:lysophospholipase 1, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 35 // 35 // 8 // 23 // 1 /// GENSCAN00000004993 // ENSEMBL // cdna:genscan chromosome:GRCm38:1:4807409:4845016:1 transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 48 // 48 // 11 // 23 // 1 /// NONMMUT000037 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Exonic // chr1 // 35 // 35 // 8 // 23 // 1", 
"NM_001159750 // RefSeq // Mus musculus transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 (Tcea1), transcript variant 3, mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// NM_011541 // RefSeq // Mus musculus transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1 (Tcea1), transcript variant 2, mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000081551 // ENSEMBL // ensembl_havana_transcript:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:4857814:4897905:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000033813 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// BC061490 // GenBank // Mus musculus transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:70239 IMAGE:2582185), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// BC083127 // GenBank // Mus musculus transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:103154 IMAGE:6390364), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// M18210 // GenBank // Mouse transcription factor S-II, clone PSII-3. // chr1 // 100 // 63 // 5 // 5 // 0 /// BC006022 // GenBank // Mus musculus transcription elongation factor A (SII) 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:6153 IMAGE:3590733), complete cds. // chr1 // 63 // 100 // 5 // 8 // 0", 
"NM_133826 // RefSeq // Mus musculus ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H (Atp6v1h), mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 30 // 30 // 0 /// XM_006495437 // RefSeq // PREDICTED: Mus musculus ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H (Atp6v1h), transcript variant X5, mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 53 // 16 // 16 // 0 /// XM_006495438 // RefSeq // PREDICTED: Mus musculus ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H (Atp6v1h), transcript variant X6, mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 53 // 16 // 16 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000044369 // ENSEMBL // ensembl:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:5083173:5162549:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000033793 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 30 // 30 // 0 /// BC009154 // GenBank // Mus musculus ATPase, H+ transporting, lysosomal V1 subunit H, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:11985 IMAGE:3601621), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 93 // 28 // 28 // 0 /// AK034165 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus adult male diencephalon cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:9330160M17 product:similar to MSTP042 [Homo sapiens], full insert sequence. // chr1 // 73 // 73 // 22 // 30 // 1 /// AK081492 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus 16 days embryo head cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:C130021C16 product:hypothetical V-ATPase subunit H containing protein, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 40 // 40 // 12 // 30 // 1 /// GENSCAN00000045875 // ENSEMBL // cdna:genscan chromosome:GRCm38:1:5084460:5217241:1 transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 80 // 80 // 24 // 30 // 1", 
"NM_001204371 // RefSeq // Mus musculus opioid receptor, kappa 1 (Oprk1), transcript variant 1, mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// NM_011011 // RefSeq // Mus musculus opioid receptor, kappa 1 (Oprk1), transcript variant 2, mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000027038 // ENSEMBL // ensembl_havana_transcript:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:5588557:5602866:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025905 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000160339 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:5588941:5604014:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025905 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 88 // 22 // 22 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000160777 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:5588493:5606131:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025905 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// BC116795 // GenBank // Mus musculus opioid receptor, kappa 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:151172 IMAGE:40126114), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// BC119026 // GenBank // Mus musculus opioid receptor, kappa 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:155342 IMAGE:8733775), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// L11065 // GenBank // Mouse kappa opioid receptor mRNA, complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000159083 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:5596518:5603153:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025905 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:retained_intron // chr1 // 72 // 72 // 18 // 25 // 1 /// AK138198 // GenBank HTC // Mus musculus adult male hypothalamus cDNA, RIKEN full-length enriched library, clone:A230031G11 product:opioid receptor, kappa 1, full insert sequence. // chr1 // 56 // 56 // 14 // 25 // 1 /// GENSCAN00000045874 // ENSEMBL // cdna:genscan chromosome:GRCm38:1:5578692:5633299:1 transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 96 // 24 // 24 // 0", 
"NM_009826 // RefSeq // Mus musculus RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 (Rb1cc1), mRNA. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 29 // 29 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000027040 // ENSEMBL // ensembl_havana_transcript:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:6214645:6276648:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025907 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 29 // 29 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000159530 // ENSEMBL // havana:putative chromosome:GRCm38:1:6262933:6274489:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025907 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 31 // 9 // 9 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000159656 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:6270678:6275575:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025907 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:retained_intron // chr1 // 100 // 28 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000161327 // ENSEMBL // havana:novel chromosome:GRCm38:1:6234279:6275577:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025907 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 100 // 86 // 25 // 25 // 0 /// ENSMUST00000162257 // ENSEMBL // havana:known chromosome:GRCm38:1:6249088:6274490:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025907 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:nonsense_mediated_decay // chr1 // 100 // 38 // 11 // 11 // 0 /// AB050017 // GenBank // Mus musculus CC1 mRNA for coiled-coil protein, complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 93 // 27 // 27 // 0 /// AB070619 // GenBank // Mus musculus Rb1cc1 mRNA for transcription factor, complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 100 // 29 // 29 // 0 /// BC150774 // GenBank // Mus musculus RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1, mRNA (cDNA clone MGC:183685 IMAGE:9087685), complete cds. // chr1 // 100 // 83 // 24 // 24 // 0 /// XM_006495444 // RefSeq // PREDICTED: Mus musculus RB1-inducible coiled-coil 1 (Rb1cc1), transcript variant X2, mRNA. // chr1 // 66 // 66 // 19 // 29 // 1 /// ENSMUST00000162795 // ENSEMBL // havana:putative chromosome:GRCm38:1:6228002:6249029:1 gene:ENSMUSG00000025907 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 34 // 34 // 10 // 29 // 1 /// NONMMUT000060 // NONCODE // Non-coding transcript identified by NONCODE: Exonic // chr1 // 100 // 28 // 8 // 8 // 0 /// GENSCAN00000007874 // ENSEMBL // cdna:genscan chromosome:GRCm38:1:6214132:6428628:1 transcript_biotype:protein_coding // chr1 // 59 // 59 // 17 // 29 // 1"
), category = c("main", "main", "main", "main", "main", "main", 
"main", "main", "main", "main")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any gene name here in the GPL file, but they are separated by //es.
First I suggest you please edit them and then review, as it'll make life easier.

Sample code from another similar question by which solves the problem is:

```
catchwords <- c('foo', 'bar', 'tex18')

d <- data.frame(tags = c("af285583 // tex18 // testis expressed gene 18 // 10 c1|10 // 83559",
                         "tic // tac // toe"
                         )
                )

d$has_catchword <-
  d$tags |>
  ## splits at two or more slashes with possibly adjacent blanks:
  strsplit(d$tags, split = ' ?/ ?{2,}') |> 
  Map(f = \(fragments) intersect(fragments, catchwords) |> length() |> as.logical()) |>
  unlist()
```

Source: [Check values of column 1 present in values of column 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78100204/check-values-of-column-1-present-in-values-of-column-2/78100464#78100464)

Once you have done it, maybe we can look into this together?

Comment: Even after I do that, there are duplicates, in the rows for genes and I want to avoid that while at the same time I want to directly match it with the gene's ensembl id as I have mentioned in the question directly. if you happen to know of any database that will be very helpful :)

Comment: also there are a couple of online webtools to perform the task. i am looking for R functions which can help with this.